Cannot Connect to the Room by CustomRoomProperties
I am new to Photon pun2 development, i want to create a muliplayer game where when HOST create room it will come with a random String, which the other players have to insert to get into room. But in my implementations it is not working.
Also what is difference between a room and lobby
Here's the code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class OnlineLauncher : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
public static OnlineLauncher instance;
public string roomIDToJoin;

private byte maxPlayersPerRoom = 2;

public bool notConnected = true;

string gameVersion = "1.0";
void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null )
    {
        instance = this;
        Debug.Log("OnlineLauncher instance filled");
    }

    PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
}

void Update()
{
    
}

public void ConnectToMasterServer()
{
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
}

public void JoinRoomByRoomID(string roomID)
{
    roomIDToJoin = roomID;
    PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
}

public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
{
    foreach(RoomInfo room in roomList)
    {
        if(room.CustomProperties.ContainsKey("roomID") && (string)room.CustomProperties["roomID"]== roomIDToJoin)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(room.Name);
            Debug.LogError("Found the room!!");
            return;
        }
    }
    Debug.LogWarning("No room Found with given ID!!");
}

public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    Debug.Log("Connected to the Photon Cloud");
    notConnected = false;
}

public override void OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause cause)
{
    Debug.LogWarningFormat("Disconnected from cloud", cause);
}

public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
{
    Debug.Log("Failed to join a room, creating new room!");
    
    //Opens a new ui window to get room name and on button click starts the new room
}

public void CreateRoom(string roomName, string roomID)
{
    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions
    {
        MaxPlayers = maxPlayersPerRoom,
        CustomRoomProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable
        {
            { "roomID", roomID }
        }

    };
    //Creates a room
    Debug.Log("Room Created");
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions);
    PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = gameVersion;

}

}
